# Git SourceTree integrate changes

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have problem with push on repository.

> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>
> hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>
> hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

But after pulling changes that was made by my friend, nothing happens.

We are working on different parts and I think that it should not be any conflicts.

We have only one branch.

[image]

Comment: We need more informations to help you. On which branch are you working. What do you means by "nothing happens" ?

Comment: I mean nothing happens that, after pulling changes they appering in code but sourcetree doesnot allow push my changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what should work in your case:

```
# Get the remote changes
# Two commits:
# - add new folder
# - add languages
git pull origin master

# This should have caused a merge commit.
# If Git asks you to provide a commit message, do that.
# If there are conflicts, fix them and commit the changes
# After that, push your changes (merge commit + UI balance update)
git push origin master
```

This is pretty much the standard workflow - this works for pretty much everyone. If one of the commands shows an error, please update your question.

These things are best done from command line - understanding the underlying Git commands will be beneficial for you in the long run.